# Compiler error message with cout

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, stdio

**I mistyped the error message before. It is fixed now.**

I'm currently getting the following compiler error message

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << Collection::operator[](int)(j)'
```

The code that the compiler is complaining about is

```
cout << testingSet[j];
```

Where `testingSet` is an object of type `Collection` that has `operator[]` overloaded to return an object of type `Example`.  `Example` has a friend function that overloads `operator<<` for ostream and Example.

note: this actually compiles just fine within Visual Studio; however does not compile using g++.

Here is the implementation of `operator<<`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &strm, Example &ex)
{
     strm << endl << endl;
     strm << "{ ";
     map<string, string>::iterator attrib;
     for(attrib = ex.attributes.begin(); attrib != ex.attributes.end(); ++attrib)
     {
          strm << "(" << attrib->first << " = " << attrib->second << "), ";
     }
     return strm << "} classification = " << (ex.classification ? "true" : "false") << endl;
}
```

And the `operator[]`

```
Example Collection::operator[](int i)
{
      return examples[i];
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing what you think the implementation is - post the actual implementation. It obviously is not what you think it is.

Comment: Can you point us in the direction of the documentation for `std::Collection`? I've not come across this part of the C++ Standard Library before.

Comment: Have you `#include` the file that contains the `Collection` definition? - it looks like the compiler can't find it (not even in the `std` namespace - which I guess you are `using`)

Comment: @johnsyweb: std::Collection is not part of the C++ Standard library.  It is my own defined class.

Comment: @Tom: Yes I have `#include` the file. It is strange because it compiles just fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: (also, I would try to get out of the habit of writing `using namespace std` and into the habit of writing `std::ostream` and `std::cout`).

Comment: @littleadv: I have posted the implementation of the `operator<<`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: So why on Earth is it qualified with `std::`? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/320798/78845

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `operator[]`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I realized that I accidentally miscopied the error message. Now it is fixed.

Comment: @interjay: It just takes an int and returns the the `Example` stored at that index of a `vector` that is stored in the `Collection` object.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm sure it does, but we still need to see it, particularly to see its signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably your operator should be declared as:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &strm, const Example &ex)
```

Note the const-reference to Example.
Visual Studio has an *extension* that allows to bind a reference to a non-const r-value. My guess is that your `operator[]` returns an r-value.

Anyway, an `operator<<` should be `const` as it is not expected to modify the written object.

Comment: Yes, but then I cannot use iterators in the way that I have in my implementation. How could I fix that?

Comment: Using `map<string, string>::const_iterator attrib;`? You are not modifying the object, are you?

Comment: Aha! That was it. I didn't know about the const_iterator. Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, a jumped the gun a little bit. I'm actually still getting the error :(

Comment: Ah, but now it is fixed. Making the `operator[]` return a `const string` was the final touch.

Comment: @Daniel: "a `const string`"? How does that tie in with you question!?