# Difference between "using namespace std" and "namespace std"?

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

```
#ifndef DATE_H_
#define DATE_H_

namespace std {

class Date {
    public:
       Date();
       virtual ~Date();
    };

} /* namespace std */

#endif /* DATE_H_ */
```

I created class Date for my assignment, and it created
the `namespace std{......}`. I don't know the use of it.
why it is not written as usual `use namespace std;`
what is the difference?

Answer (score 7):

Your code declares your class Date within the namespace std, i.e. your class fully qualified name would be std::Date

A statement

```
using namepace std;
```

Will include the namespace std when searching for symbols.

Some additional notes:

1. The standard explicitly says that adding things to the std namespace can lead to undefined behaviours making it not only a bad practice but outside of the standard. See [Adding types to the std namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320798/adding-types-to-the-std-namespace) for a detailed discussion.
2. It's not a good practice to use `using namespace` on a *.h (or anything that get included in multiple files)... because it might have unexpected side-effects with symbols resolved to wrong namespaces.

Comment: It's not just bad practice: it's prohibited.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Refined the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

First of all: you shouldn't put anything in the `std` namespace, ever.

```
namespace foo
{
  class A {};
}
```

puts the class `A` in the namespace `foo`, so its full name is `foo::A`.

```
using namespace foo;
```

means that you can access all the things that are in `foo` without using the qualifier `foo::`.
Note that `using namespace` is generally frowned upon and can lead to many unexpected problems.
Most importantly, don't write it in headers.

If you say

```
using namespace foo;

class A{};
```

`A` is not inside `foo`, but in the global namespace.

Comment: Technically, you might want to put a specialization of `std::swap` in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I thought that issue had been solved so we didn't need that hack any more.