# Overloading for_each for specific iterator types

Tags: c++

I'm using a typedef to define the type of a container in my program so that I can easily switch between using normal STL containers and [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) containers, along the lines of:

```
typedef stxxl:vector<Data> MyContainer;
```

or

```
typedef std:vector<Data> MyContainer;
```

One difficulty is that STXXL provides a special version of `std::for_each`, `stxxl::for_each` that is optimised for use with STXXL containers. I'd prefer to use this function when MyContainer is typedeffed as a `stxxl::vector`.

One solution would be to define my own `for_each` function that calls the right `for_each` function and use that whenever I want to call `for_each`.

Another solution that I'm currently investigating is to overload/specialize `std::foreach` so that it calls `stxxl::for_each` whenever it is called with a `stxxl::vector<Data>::(const_)iterator` as first and second argument.

I cannot get the second idea to work though. I've tried the following:

```
namespace std
{
    template <class UnaryFunction>
    UnaryFunction for_each(stxxl:vector<Data>::const_iterator first, 
        stxxl:vector<Data>::const_iterator last, UnaryFunction f)
    {
        stxxl::for_each(first, last, f, 4);
    }
}
```

Along with a similar function for non-const iterators. They don't get called though.

What would be the preferred solution to this problem? How can I get my version of `std::for_each` for `stxxl::vector` iterators to get called?

**Update:** I got the second idea to work now, as posted. The problem was that I was including the wrong file (ouch...). The first question remains though: What is the preferred solution to this problem? Is it okay to overload std::for_each, as the std namespace is not intended for mere mortals?

Comment: I can never remember the rules for what you are allowed to inject into the std namespacem and I bet most other people can't either. So I would prefer the non-invasive solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specialize templates in std (17.4.3.1), but you can't add overloads. Your definition is an overload, not a specialization of the standard for_each template, and in any case functions can't be partially specialized. So it's undefined to put any definition in namespace std that might do what you want.

ADL is supposed to make this work smoothly without any need for that, though. I assume the stxxl iterators are in the stxxl namespace, so `for_each(first, last, f, 4);` should call `stxxl::for_each`. If you want `std::for_each`, you fully qualify the name when you call it.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I would like to say that you want to inject into the `std` namespace, it really is a sticky wicket as Neil pointed out.  The [related thread of `std::swap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap/109613#109613) points out a number of the details as does the now infamous [USENET discussion on the subject](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/b396fedad7dcdc81).

To sum it up, the only way that you are allowed to inject a name into `std` is if you can fully specialize it.  So, you can write:

```
namespace std {
    template <>
    MyFunction for_each(stxxl::vector<Data>::const_iterator first,
                        stxxl::vector<Data>::const_iterator last,
                        MyFunction func)
    {
        return stxxl::for_each(first, last, func);
    }
}
```

for every combination of container and function and you are well within the rules.  Unfortunately, partial function template specialization doesn't exist in the current incarnation of the Standard.  If you are really curious, dedicate an evening to reading the entire [USENET post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/b396fedad7dcdc81).  It really is quite enlightening and a little frightening.  You can probably write a nifty macro (gasp) to automate this for you if you only use a few type/function combinations.

You can use [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_dependent_name_lookup) to solve the problem as well provided that none of the `stxxl` stuff simply exposes an iterator from `std` using a typedef.  I believe that this is generally the preferred solution today.

I would add your own wrapper around `for_each` that forwards to the appropriate one and call it done.  This isn't the most elegant, but it will work now and doesn't rely on any magic to make it happen.

Comment: It's not just your opinion that it's unusable; partial *function* template specialization doesn't exist, although that's the feature TC was attempting to use.

Comment: There is no such thing as specialization or partial specialization of functions - only overloads (which can look like what you think of as a template class specialization)

Comment: "provided that none of the stxxl stuff simply exposes an iterator from std using a typedef". If it does, then getting std::for_each is probably fine. We're told that stxxl::for_each is an optimisation for the stxxl containers. So if some stxxl iterator is really a std iterator, then I'd wager that whatever optimisations apply to other stxxl iterators, don't apply to that one.

Comment: @Terry: no, there is such a thing as explicit specialization of a function template. For example: `typedef void (*func)(int*); namespace std { template<> func for_each(int *first, int *last, func f) { while(first != last) f(first++); return f; } }` is a complete specialization of the standard for_each template. It's not the same as an overload, although usually overloads are preferred.

Comment: @Rob: thanks. I couldn't recall if it existed in a completely broken form or didn't exist at all. I updated the post.

@Steve: thanks. I tried to make sure that I got all of the terminology correct.

Answer (score 1):

std::for_each  is a public well documented algorithm function,   I don't think I wound like it if some library I am using goes around changing it ;-.  Possibly other parts of my program need the good old for_each

So I would go with the solution that doesn't break this interface and leaves std::for_each as it is.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize:

- There is no such thing as partial specialization of functions. Only overloading that function with your specific types
- It is generally forbidden to put stuff in namespace std
- What you really want is to put an overload for for_each in the namespace of the specific iterator types ("next to") you're overloading on. This ensures ADL will find it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try and specialize std::for_each().
Especially since what you want is partial specialization.

Rather I would write a function that used std::for_each() but had a specialization for stlxxl.
I don't have stlxxl so I have done some code that demonstrates what I mean.

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

//
// Normal version.
template<typename U,typename T,typename A,template<class I,class A> class C>
U Ufor_each(C<T,A>& cont,U const& f)
{
    std::cout << "NORMAL Start" << std::endl;
    return std::for_each(cont.begin(),cont.end(),f);
    return f;
}

// 
// Specialized version.
// You could write a specialized version for stlxxl::vector
template<typename U,typename T>
U Ufor_each(std::vector<T>& cont,U const& f)
{
    std::cout << "Vector Start" << std::endl;
    return std::for_each(cont.begin(),cont.end(),f);
}

struct X
{
    void operator()(int data) const
    {
        std::cout << "Item: " << data << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>    vect;
    std::list<int>      list;

    vect.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(4);

    X                   x;
    Ufor_each(vect,x);
    Ufor_each(list,x);
}
```

I tried but failed to get it working with iterators.

Comment: You're overloading Ufor_each here, not partially specializing