# Can I get the "iterator" for a template type, regardless if that type is an array or STL-like container?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++11

Here's my example:

```
template<typename TContainer>
class MyClass
{
public:
   typedef typename SomeUnknownHelper<TContainer>::iterator iterator;
};

std::vector<int>::iterator i = MyClass<std::vector<int>>::iterator;
int *pi = MyClass<int[20]>::iterator;
```

Basically, I don't know how to write `SomeUnknownHelper`.

I know I could specialize `MyClass` itself, but in my real-world case it would be a hassle because the class is large.

Comment: Apparently I wasn't thinking things through correctly. Any one of these answers does what I want, and simply. Thanks.

Comment: So now my question is, do I want to prefer supporting `begin`/`end`, or iterators...

Comment: Why not both? What's hindering you?

Comment: Well, I can't say `typedef ContainerTrait<T>::iterator iterator; typedef decltype(tricks::adl_begin(std::declval<TContainer>())) iterator;` --I have to pick just one.

Comment: Ah. Well, why not put the `begin` thingy inside `ContainerTrait`? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easily doable with `decltype` and `std::begin`:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

namespace tricks{
  using std::begin; // fallback for ADL
  template<class C>
  auto adl_begin(C& c) -> decltype(begin(c)); // undefined, not needed
  template<class C>
  auto adl_begin(C const& c) -> decltype(begin(c)); // undefined, not needed
}

template<typename TContainer>
class MyClass
{
public:
   typedef decltype(tricks::adl_begin(std::declval<TContainer>())) iterator;
};

std::vector<int>::iterator i = MyClass<std::vector<int>>::iterator;
int *pi = MyClass<int[20]>::iterator;
```

An even better option might be using Boost.Range:

```
#include <boost/range/metafunctions.hpp>

template<typename TContainer>
class MyClass
{
public:
   typedef typename boost::range_iterator<TContainer>::type iterator;
};

std::vector<int>::iterator i = MyClass<std::vector<int>>::iterator;
int *pi = MyClass<int[20]>::iterator;
```

Comment: I'm still learning C++11, but I don't think I understand the complexity of the `tricks` interface.  Why couldn't you just directly call `std::begin`?

Comment: @templatetypedef: To enable ADL, argument dependent lookup. Basically, to support user-defined types that overload their own version of `begin` (and `end`).

Comment: @Xeo- Couldn't a custom container just add its own overload of `std::begin`?  Or is the intent that `begin` is not placed in the standard namespace?

Comment: @templatetypedef: You are not allowed to put anything in namespace `std` unless told otherwise. And that otherwise is currently only specializations of certain class or function templates, though no partial specialization "officially". So, you *could* specialize `std::begin`, but... [specializations suck *hard*](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm). :)

Comment: although specializing std::begin is allowed you're supposed to just provide your own version inside your own namespace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap/8439357#8439357

Comment: @templatetypedef: Oh yeah, another thing, partial specialization of function templates isn't possible *at all*. :)

Comment: I switched to this as my preferred answer, since I was already requiring `begin(container)` to compile, but I wasn't requiring `container_type::iterator` anywhere other than to resolve the iterator type.

Answer (score 1):

That's only one single specialization, how bad could that be?

```
template <typename T> struct ContainerTrait
{
    typedef typename T::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename T::const_iterator const_iterator;
};

template <typename T, unsigned int N> struct ContainerTrait<T[N]>
{
    typedef T * iterator;
    typedef T const * const_iterator;
};
```

Alternatively, you can use the free `std::begin`/`std::end` and `auto`:

```
auto it = std::begin(x);  // x could be vector<int> or float[10]...
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I couldn't get this working before. I think I was forgetting the `<T[N]>` at the end of the template specialization, but it's long gone now and I can't be sure.