# std:: qualifier needed when overloaded namespace function exists?

Tags: c++, c++11, name-lookup

If I have a little bit of code like:

```
using namespace std;

namespace myNamespace
{
    vector<float> sqrt( vector<float> v ) { return v; }

    void func()
    {
        vector<float> myVec = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        std::cout << sqrt( myVec )[0] << std::endl;
        float myFloat = 4.0f;
        std::cout << sqrt( myFloat ) << std::endl; // need to use std::sqrt()
    }
}
```

then it won't compile unless I changed the marked line to use `std::sqrt`. Why? I understand that if I tried to redefine `sqrt(float)` in `myNamespace` then I'd have to qualify with `std::` if I wanted the standard library version to be used. The compiler appears to try to convert `myFloat` rather than just use a function in another (`std`) namespace.

One way I found to get around this is to define `sqrt(vector<float>)` in the `std` namespace but that doesn't quite feel right and answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402990/should-you-overload-swap-in-the-std-namespace) suggest overloading in `std` is illegal. Probably not the way to go then...

How can I overload `sqrt` (or any other standard library cmath function, for that matter) so that I don't have to always qualify which one to use and have the compiler select based on the passed function parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: Declaring your own function in the `std` namespace is definitely wrong. You *could* declare it in the global namespace, since you've dumped `std` in there for some reason. Or you could add `using std::sqrt;` to your namespace, alongside your `sqrt`. I'd just qualify the name properly.

Comment: You could also just not use use `using namespace somethingsomething` and always use the std:: prefix, avoiding crap like this altogether.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++, [name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) doesn't care about parameters type, only the *name* matters. When the compiler looks for a function named `sqrt`, it will always find your version first (since the lookup starts with the enclosing namespace), and stops there.

You must help the compiler by bringing the name from `std::` into scope with a [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using) directive in your namespace :

```
namespace myNamespace
{
  using std::sqrt
  ...
}
```

Then, standard overload resolution will take place to distinguish between your `sqrt` and [`std::sqrt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt), and will select the correct `sqrt` function to be called.

To avoid any ambiguity, you should always qualify the name (`std::sqrt` or `myNamespace::sqrt`)

---

**Notes:**

- As pointed out by Simple, [Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) makes [`std::sqrt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) available for name lookup in the first case (since `vector` is in `std::`), but it doesn't change the problem you're facing.
- Declaring your own `sqrt` function in `std::` is a very bad idea (forbidden  by the standard, except for template specializations)

Comment: Is there a way to bring all std:: names into the current namespace? Something like using std::*?

Comment: It does care about the parameter types though. In the first call to `sqrt` the compiler will have found both `myNamespace::sqrt` and `std::sqrt` via ADL (because `vector` is in `std`). It only chooses `myNamespace::sqrt` because it's a better match.

Answer (score 3):

You can bring `std::sqrt` into your namespace via the statement `using std::sqrt;` within `myNamespace`:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    vector<float> sqrt( vector<float> v ) { return v; }
    using std::sqrt;
    ...
```

Then the compiler will pick the appropriate `sqrt` in `std::cout << sqrt( myFloat )`