# Calling a template member function having existing name

Tags: c++, templates, name-lookup

please see the following code:

```
namespace std {
    template <std::size_t I, class T>
    auto& get(my_tuple_like_type<T>& t)
    {
        std::size_t ext = t.template extent<I>(); // This line
        // .... do something with ext and return
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to specialize (overload) `std::get` to make my own class template `my_tuple_like_type` somewhat `std::tuple`-like.

But gcc 5.4.0 complains that the constant `I` is not a type name. It seems that the reason is there is already a name `std::extent` which is a class template.

A workaround I can think of is to forward the call to a free-standing implementation function declared outside `namespace std`. But I wonder, **is this the right behavior according to the standard?** Or is it just another bug of gcc?

I guess this should be a bug, since clang and MSVC both compile the above code just fine. On the other hand, Nvidia's CUDA compiler (nvcc) produces a similar error message.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Providing overloads inside `namespace std` is forbidden ([Should you overload swap in the std namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402990/should-you-overload-swap-in-the-std-namespace)), so I was doing a wrong thing.

But I can't see potential problems this may induce. Is there any reason why overloadings on user-defined types are forbidden?

Comment: Why are you breaching `std`? To do so leaves your program with undefined behavior officially. You should put your class in a namesapce, add a `my_namesapce::get` function, and let ADL do the rest.

Comment: @StoryTeller AFAIK, specializing templates in std with respect to my own type is OK. For example, ``std::iterator_traits`` is even intended to be specialized by users, isn't it?

Comment: @JunekeyJeon I was about to reply the same thing to StoryTeller, but this is actually an overload, not a specialization, so UB indeed.

Comment: @Quentin Hmm, but it is then impossible to customize the behavior of ``std::get`` when dealing with user-defined class templates, so I think this must be permitted..., and I don't think the standard indeed banned this.

Comment: @JunekeyJeon - [It very much bans it](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#1). Adding an overload falls under adding definitions. Specialization is a different beast.

Comment: It's forbidden because standard library implementors may need to introduce helper classes/functions to implement standard behavior. And the standard committee doesn't want to limit them in pursuing good clean efficient implementations. Other than the public names defined for namesapce std, all other identifiers within are reserved to the implementors.

Comment: @JunekeyJeon - the trick is to not overload a template function in namespace `std`.   See if you can get the behaviour you need using a `std::tuple`, rather than implementing your own tuple type.   That way, among other things, you won't need to mess around trying to overload a function from namespace `std`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you very much, but i can't understand how what you said is related to prevention of providing overloads for user-defined types..

Comment: @JunekeyJeon - Because you cannot know if the implementor uses their own `my_tuple_like_type` in any way shape or form, or how names in your implementation will be resolved inside namespace std (this is precisely why your error occurs, btw).

Comment: @StoryTeller Okay, I understand something may become wrong with unqualified identifiers, but how about fully qualified identifiers? And it is still unclear to me if resolving ````extent```` in ````t.template extent<I>```` to ````std::extent```` is right.... What should happen if I change ````std```` to some other namespace containing a template class ````extent````? GCC still thinks ````extent```` is not a member of ````t````....