# Uniform Interface for Math functions for custom and standard type

Tags: c++

I have some custom types `a::Vector` in a `namespace a` for which I have defined some math functions `a::abs`, `a::pow` and `a::isnan` among others. I want to be able to call `abs(T t)` without having to worry about whether the argument `T` is a `double` or a `a::Vector`. Using just `abs` everywhere correctly uses `a::abs` for `a::Vector` using ADL, however defaults to using `C`-style `abs(int t)` function even for `double` arguments while I want it to use `std::abs` or `fabs`.

I do not want to use `using std::abs` declarations since this are considered bad in general. What are my options to have a uniform interface `abs(T t)` for all the different types?

Comment: Well, this could be one use case where `using std::abs;` might not be unreasonable. What's really bad is yanking the entire kit and kaboodle with 'using namespace std;'. Or, alternatively, you can define a similarly-named template function, say `Abs()`, and then specialize it for your vector, and `double`, as nothing more than wrappers for the real functions.

Comment: This is currently the only answer I am coming up with too, but I am not sure if I am missing anything. I will wait for a certain amount of days and then just go with the using std::abs directive since I assume that no other header file will be touching it and so, it should remain preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `template<class T> abs(T x)` were defined in `std`, then you could specialize that template, but there is no such generic template for `std::abs`. Adding overloads to `namespace std` is undefined behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14403772

I would recommend `using std::abs;`. There is generally nothing wrong with `using` specific functions; it's only `using namespace` that's bad.

Comment: Just a comment, the definition is overloading the abs function, isn't that undefined by the standard, that you cannot overload functions in std?

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik you are correct, overloads are not allowed. It also looks like `std::abs` also does not have an appropriate template, so you cannot get around this with a template specialization as you can with swap (described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14403772 ). I will edit my answer accordingly.