# Should I specialize or overload templates defined in a namespace like `std::swap`?

Tags: c++, overloading, swap

If I have some class type that manages, for example, a resource, and my class needs to define a `swap()` function as a part of its interface that works on objects of that type, then I usually do:

```cpp
struct Foo{};

Foo f1, f2;

void swap(Foo& lhs, Foo& rhs){
    // code to swap member data of lhs and rhs
}

int main(){
    using std::swap;
    Foo f1, f2;
    swap(f1, f2);
}
```

- Now, am I overloading `std::swap`, or specializing it?
- I have learned that if I want to specialize a function/class template of the standard library, then I should open the namespace `std` and declare the specialization there. e.g:

```cpp
namespace std{
    void swap(Foo&, Foo&);
}
```

- I remember that when specializing `std::hash` for my types that I intend to using as the element type to unordered associative containers, like `std::unordered_map`, I do specialize `std::hash` this way:

```cpp
namespace std{ // opening namespace std
    template<>
    class hash<Foo>{
          //...
    };
}
```

So, is this correct? Should I overload or specialize `std::swap`?

Comment: I would argue, for swap, you should always declare your swap overload in your own namespace, and let ADL find it.  See first answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402990/should-you-overload-swap-in-the-std-namespace

Answer (score 2):

The standard doesn't generally allow adding overloads or specializations in namespace `std`:

> **[namespace.std]/1** Unless otherwise specified, the behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std`.

There's an exception for specializing class templates. Your `std::hash<Foo>` example falls under that:

> **[namespace.std]/2** Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace `std` provided that (a) the added declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and (b) the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

You can overload certain standard library functions **outside** namespace `std`, relying on ADL for them to be found:

> **[namespace.std]/7** Other than in namespace `std` or in a namespace within namespace `std`, a program may provide an overload for any library function template designated as a *customization point*, provided that (a) the overload’s declaration depends on at least one user-defined type and (b) the overload meets the standard library requirements for the customization point. [*Note:* This permits a (qualified or unqualified) call to the customization point to invoke the most appropriate overload for the given arguments. *—end note*]

`std::swap` is in fact a customization point.