# Template class in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am using a template class to set the data type for a swap function. In the code if i initialize the function name as lower case letter it throws an error 
    `call of overloaded 'swap(double&, double&) is ambiguous`
but when i initialize the function name as upper case it works fine.
Will appreciate if someone could explain me why this is happening. Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
template <class T>
void swap(T &a,T &b)
{
    T temp;

    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    double value1 = 2.44;
    double value2 = 6.66;

    cout<<"\tBefore swap \n";
    cout<<"Value 1 = "<< value1 <<"\tValue 2 = " << value2 <<"\n";

    swap(value1,value2);

    cout<<"\tafter swap \n";
    cout<<"Value 1 = "<< value1 <<"\tValue 2 = "<<value2;
}
```

Comment: `std::swap` is written in a way that it can be customized for your own types, but the process is quite obscure. Look at the first **two** answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap After you did that, just use `std::swap`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
swap(value1,value2);
```

use

```
::swap(value1,value2);
```

This would solve the namespace and ambiguity issue.

Answer (score 1):

because there is already a standard library function `std::swap` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/ so possibly your compiler does not like it? You pull that in via `using namespace std;`

Comment: Yet another reason to abolish `using namespace std`

Comment: and to put own code in dedicated namespaces when possible

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your `swap` function because `std::swap` already exists.

Or you could put it in a separate namespace and use the scope resolution operator, "::", to distinguish yours from the standard one.

This is what happens when you use `namespace std;`.  You may want to be more specific and use:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Already standard library function  is defined with templates 'swap' Instead of 'SWAP',It is actually under the std namespace, but because you have a using namespace std line, it exists without the std:: prefix.

As you can see, using the using namespace std isn't always a good option because of possible name collisions, as in this example. In general one should prefer not to use the using directive unless there's a real reason for this - namespaces exist for a reason - to prevent name collisions.