# destructor called twice when removing element from vector

Tags: c++

Running the following test code

```
int destroyed[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };

struct Test {
    int a;
    Test() {}
    ~Test() {
        destroyed[a]++;
    }
};

template<class T>
void remove(std::vector<T>& v, size_t i) {
    std::swap(v[i], v.back());
    v.pop_back();
}

main() {
    std::vector<Test> vt(3);
    vt[0].a = 0;
    vt[1].a = 1;
    vt[2].a = 2;
    remove(vt, 0);
}
```

`destroyed` counts the number of times an element has been destroyed.

I can see that `destroyed = { 2, 0, 0 }`.

I want to remove element `0`, so I should destroy it. However I don't need to call its destructor twice; so, how can I write the `remove` function so that I end up with `destroyed = { 1, 0, 0 }` (destroying it only once)?

Comment: Write a move constructor for Test.

Comment: The Test class is only for testing the `remove` function. `remove` should behave correctly for every class.

Comment: Because `std::swap(v[i], v.back());` doesn't find a move constructor or `swap` specialisation, it falls back on copying `v[i=0]` to a temporary so it can overwrite it with `v.back()` then assign `v.back()` from the temporary.  The temporary will have `a == 0` due to the default copy-constructor, so when its destructor runs it increments `destroyed[0]`.  Later, `v.back()`'s destructor increments it again.  Tell the compiler how to swap `Test` objects without a temporary, or add `move` for `Test` that puts the moved object into special state (e.g. `a = -1`) then `if (a != -1) ++destroyed[a]`.

Comment: Yeah, it is behaving correctly. When you call std::swap on two elements, there's copying going on. When c++ copies an object, it doesn't move it from one place to another, it destroys it in one place and recreates it at another. Now, if your class T had a move constructor, the std::vector could use that to MOVE the object around, rather than copy it.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap) for tips on implementing `Test::swap` (probably simpler than supporting `move`).

Comment: I suggest you count constructors as well as destructors, and don't forget copy construction. You will find that the books do balance.

Comment: I think this has undefined behaviour because the `std::vector<Test> vt(3);` is allowed to create a temporary and then copy-construct the 3 vector members from it.  (well - my test program did that). Suggest changing the constructor to initialize `a`, and you can re-zero the `destroyed` array after the vector has been created and before you `remove`.

Comment: Ideally I would call `i`s element destructor, copy the last element to `i`s position and decrease the size of the vector, but `pop_back` calls the destructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation of `remove` seems to work

```
template<class T>
void remove(std::vector<T>& v, size_t i) {
    uint8_t d[sizeof T];
    memcpy(d, &v[i], sizeof T);
    v[i] = v.back();
    memcpy(&v.back(), d, sizeof T);
    v.pop_back();
}
```

Comments on this code will be very appreciated.