# Using a generic swap function to shorten the code

Tags: c++

I have the following loop (where: `Array<T> elements;`):

```
while (lengths[tempElement] == START) {
    T next = elements[tempElement];
    elements[tempElement] = elementToFind;
    tempElement = next;
}
```

I would like to use the following `swap` function:

```
void swap(T& firstElement, T& secondElement) {
    T temp = firstElement;
    firstElement = secondElement;
    secondElement = temp;
}
```

In order to shorten the code. So I used:

```
swap(elements[tempElement],elementToFind);
```

But I think it does not do what I expect. How can I use that swap function?

Answer (score 0):

Your desired code uses `T &operator=(T const&)` while `std::swap` uses `T &operator=(T&&)`.

If you want it to switch it to use the copy constructor, you can overload `std::swap` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap).

Comment: Include the relevant parts of the answer in the answer.