# How to swap strings?

Tags: c++

I am trying to swap strings. For one of my functions of my class, I am passing in two strings and I also created a temp variable. I have been trying to compile my code, but it says "no suitable function for conversion from std::string to const char* exists.

```
void CdLib::swap(string *s1, string *s2)
{
    string temp;

    strcpy(temp, *s1);
    strcpy(*s1, *s2);
    strcpy(*s1, temp);
}
```

```
class CdLib
{
public:

    int n;
    char Cd[N_MAX];

    string artist;
    string title;
    int year;
    string genre;
    string fan;
    string imageURL;

    CdLib();
    void setFromFile(string fileName);
    void print(string label);
    void sortByYear();
    void sortByArtist();
    void sortByTitle(string genres[]);

private:
    void swap(int *a, int *b);
    void swapStrings(string *s1, string *s2);
};
```

I'm confused why it is trying to convert between string and char when they should all be string. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you passing around pointers to strings? Do you know what references are? Also, unless you're trying to write it yourself, there's a `std::swap`.

Comment: You don't want the strcpy, you want operator=() or std::swap

Comment: I'm guessing `string` in your code refers to `std::string`? In that case you copy them using `=`, not `strcpy`.

Comment: strcpy works on char* not std::string.  You're confusing the C way with the C++ way.

Comment: Don’t reinvent the wheel. Read about [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Comment: Thank you everyone. I hadn't seen std::swap in any other articles or posts.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy()` takes `char*` pointers, not `string*` pointers.  It you are not allocating any memory for `strcpy()` to copy into.

Rather than using `strcpy()` at all, a better solution is to use `std::string::operator=` instead:

```cpp
void CdLib::swap(string *s1, string *s2)
{
    string temp = *s1;
    *s1 = *s2;
    *s1 = temp;
}
```

Or better, `std::swap()`:

```cpp
void CdLib::swap(string *s1, string *s2)
{
    std::swap(*s1, *s2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to swap strings

Why would you need to? Sorting can be accomplished via `std::sort` and you don't have to worry about how the strings get swapped - that's the beauty of C++, such basic operations are all implemented in the standard library.

1. `std::swap` supports pretty much everything, so use that.
2. Don't pass strings as arguments by value. Pass them by const reference. Return them by value. If a function is intended to modify a string in place, then it should take it by non-const reference (i.e. "just" a reference).
3. Don't write `using namespace std` - it's bad practice.

I guess that the `CdLib` class is some sort of a CD library, but you haven't told us what else your program should do.

If I were to write a sketch of this, I'd start with a structure representing the CD information, comparison functions for the CD that can be used in sorting, a function to print out the CD information, and a way to stream the CD information to/from an ostream/istream:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct CDInfo
{
    std::string artist;
    std::string title;
    std::string genre;
    std::string fan;
    std::string imageUrl;
    int year;

    friend void swap(CDInfo& a, CDInfo& b)
    {
        // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2684544/1329652 for rationale
        using std::swap; // bring in swap for built-in types

        swap(a.artist, b.artist);
        swap(a.title, b.title);
        swap(a.genre, b.genre);
        swap(a.fan, b.fan);
        swap(a.imageUrl, b.imageUrl);
        swap(a.year, b.year);
    }
};

bool lessByYear(const CDInfo &l, const CDInfo &r) {
    return l.year < r.year;
}

bool lessByArtist(const CDInfo &l, const CDInfo &r) {
    return l.artist < r.artist;
}

void print(std::ostream &os, const CDInfo &cd) {
    os <<   "Artist:   " << cd.artist
       << "\n  Title:  " << cd.title
       << "\n  Genre:  " << cd.genre
       << "\n  Fan:    " << cd.fan
       << "\n  Image:  " << cd.imageUrl
       << "\n  Year:   " << cd.year << "\n";
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, CDInfo &cd)
{
    std::string year;
    std::getline(is, cd.artist);
    std::getline(is, cd.title);
    std::getline(is, cd.genre);
    std::getline(is, cd.fan);
    std::getline(is, cd.imageUrl);
    if (std::getline(is, year)) cd.year = std::stoi(year);
    return is;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const CDInfo &cd)
{
    os << cd.artist << '\n' << cd.title << '\n'
       << cd.genre << '\n' << cd.fan << '\n'
       << cd.imageUrl << '\n' << cd.year << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

Then I'd write a class representing the CD library, with methods to access the individual CDs, iterators to access the entire collection, methods using the `std::sort` algorithm and the comparison functions to sort the library, and methods to load/save it from/to file, and to print the entire library (by default to stdout):

```
class CDLibrary
{
    std::vector<CDInfo> m_CDs;

public:
    CDLibrary() = default;

    int count() const { return m_CDs.size(); }
    void resize(int newCount) { m_CDs.resize(newCount); }

    CDInfo &getCD(int index) { return m_CDs[index]; }
    const CDInfo &getCD(int index) const { return m_CDs[index]; }

    auto begin() { return m_CDs.begin(); }
    auto end() { return m_CDs.end(); }
    auto begin() const { return m_CDs.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return m_CDs.end(); }
    auto cbegin() const { return m_CDs.begin(); }
    auto cend() const { return m_CDs.end(); }

    void sortByYear() {
        std::sort(begin(), end(), lessByYear);
    }

    void sortByArtist() {
        std::sort(begin(), end(), lessByArtist);
    }

    void addCD(const CDInfo &cd) {
        m_CDs.push_back(cd);
    }

    void removeCD(int index) {
        m_CDs.erase(m_CDs.begin() + index);
    }

    bool load(const std::string &filename);
    bool save(const std::string &filename) const;
    
    void printAll(std::ostream &os = std::cout) const {
        int n = 1;
        for (auto &cd : *this) {
            os << "--- CD #" << n << '\n';
            print(os, cd);
        }
    }
};
```

Of course I'd also implement the streaming operators for the entire library, just as we did for the individual CDInfo:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, CDLibrary &lib) {
    std::string count;
    if (std::getline(is, count)) {
        lib.resize(std::stoi(count));
        for (auto &cd : lib)
            if (!(is >> cd)) break;
    }
    return is;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const CDLibrary &lib) {
    if (!(os << lib.count() << '\n')) return os;
    for (auto &cd : lib)
        if (!(os << cd)) break;
    return os;
}
```

Then, the `load` and `save` convenience methods can be expressed n terms of those streaming operators:

```
bool CDLibrary::load(const std::string &filename) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    try {
        return ifs.good() && ifs >> *this;
    } catch (...) {}
    return false;
}

bool CDLibrary::save(const std::string &filename) const {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    return ofs.good() && ofs << *this;
}
```

Hopefully this gives you some idea how such code might look. I'm not quite sure what you expected to achieve with `void sortByTitle(string genres[])`, so I didn't implement it. Feel free to comment under this answer to explain, as well as edit the question to make it clear what is the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str1 = "Hello";
    string str2 = "World";
    swap(str1,str2);
    cout<<str1<<" ";
    cout<<str2;
}
```

o/p:
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4492KB
World Hello