# C++ overload of swap function not working

Tags: c++, template-specialization, specialization

I'm writing a custom class for which I want to use the std::swap function.

As I read in this post [How to overload std::swap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap) , I have to overload it in the same namespace of the object I'm trying to swap and there's an example.

I (thing) I'm replicating the example, but the function that gets called when using `std::swap()` isn't the one defined by me.

Here is what my code looks alike:

```
//grid.hpp
namespace myname {
template <typename T>
class Grid
{
    ...
    friend void swap(Grid &a, Grid &b)
    {
        using std::swap;
        std::cout << "Custom Swap Used" << std::endl;
        swap(a.nrwow, b.nrows);
        swap(a.ncols, b.ncols);
        a.grid.swap(b.grid);
    }
}
}
```

but when I call the swap function no string gets printed, so this function doesn't get called.

```
//file.cpp
#include"../src/grid.hpp"

int main() {
myname::Grid<int> grid1(10, 10);
myname::Grid<int> grid2(10, 10);
std::swap(grid1, grid2); // this should print a string
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to uses [`std::ranges::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/ranges/swap), or find it via ADL if you aren't using C++20:

```cpp
myname::Grid<int> grid1(10, 10);
myname::Grid<int> grid2(10, 10);

std::ranges::swap(grid1, grid2);

// Or with ADL
using std::swap;
swap(grid1, grid2);
```

["Swapping"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable) does not exactly mean `std::swap`, but this form of "`using std::swap; swap(x, y);`", which is encapsulated by `std::ranges::swap`.

---

Writing `std::swap(grid1, grid2)` directly calls the default [`template<typename T> void std::move(T&, T&);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). This will use the move construct and move assignment operators instead of your custom swap function, which is why you don't see `"Custom Swap Used"`.