# AUTOSAR C++ Rule 6-2-1 - Move and Copy Assignment Operators

Tags: c++, autosar, copy-assignment, move-assignment-operator

The following code violates AUTOSAR C++ rule 6-2-1: 
 **Move and copy assignment operators shall either move or respectively copy base classes and data members of a class, without any side effects. 
 Move assignment performs actions other than moving data members and base classes. 
 Extra side effects might cause performance overhead and violate class invariant.**

For detailed explanation of the rule, see [here](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/18-10/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf), page 114

###### PBufWrapper.h

```
struct PBufWrapper {
  pbuf *firstElement = nullptr;
private:
  DataSize_t m_freeSpace = 0; // (typedef uint16_t DataSize_t;)
}
```

###### PBufWrapper.cpp

```
PBufWrapper &PBufWrapper::operator=(PBufWrapper &&other) noexcept { // violates A 6-2-1
  copySimpleMembersAndResetBuffer(other); // Found extra side effect!

  if (other.firstElement != nullptr) {
    firstElement = other.firstElement;
    other.firstElement = nullptr;
  }
  return *this;
}
```

```
void PBufWrapper::copySimpleMembersAndResetBuffer(const PBufWrapper &other) {
  m_freeSpace = other.m_freeSpace;

  if (firstElement != nullptr) {
    pbuf_free(firstElement);
    firstElement = nullptr;
  }
}
```

For **pbuf_free** see: [here](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_0_x/group__pbuf.html#gab0dd696fb4b6bc65e548944584f1738b)

###### I tried two things

1. Test for Self-Assignment in `operator=()`: `if (&other != *this) { ... }`
2. `std::swap(*this, other);` in `operator=()`

These were not the solutions.

I would be very happy if someone can explain me how to solve it.

###### Edit

Related to the comment by "*n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m*", I would like to know **how I can overload std::swap and do an elementwise swap in this case**?

Comment: `std::swap` is a solution, if you overload it and do an elementwise swap.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks. I am new to C++ and am not sure how to overload it.

Comment: e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap